# Unable to parse data inside h4 tag: Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am facing an issue while parsing data from the 'Literature ' tab from the third table. The steps I took to reach the table:

- Go to ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#!
- Type and select AKT1 (3 mutations) (NOTE:'GO' button doesn't work, please click the option from the drop-down)
- Click on the green button with the text 'MS', a new table will appear.
- In this new table, there will be a tab called literature, I need the literature text and the PMID.

I tried the following code, but it gives an empty list:

```
xyz= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Literature')]").click()
    for elements in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tab-pane ng-scope active"]'):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': "literature_div"})
        table_body = table.find('h4')
        rows = table.find_all('h4')
        for row in rows:
             cols = row.find_all('h4')
             # cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
             litrature.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])  # Get rid of empty value
             print("Data from COLUMN 1:")
             print(litrature)
```

How can I resolve this?

**UPDATE**
When I try to click on the 'Next ' button under the 'literature' table, I get the following error:
 "Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed " 
Following is the line I added to click on the "NEXT" buton: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)"]').click()`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is there an URL you can share and the rest of your code ? The relevant HTML would help, inserted using the snippet tool available via [edit].

Comment: @QHarr The following is the URL: ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#!
Steps to reach the table: - Go to ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#! - Type and select AKT1 (3 mutations) (NOTE:'GO' button doesn't work, please click the option from the drop-down) - Click on the green button with the text 'MS', a new table will appear. - In this new table, there will be a tab called literature, I need the literature text and the PMID from the table under Literature

Comment: @QHarr I am facing an error while clicking on the 'NEXT' button under the Literature table.
Message: The element reference of is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait 3 times

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#!/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , '//input')))
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input")
input.send_keys("AKT1\n")

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , 'btn-tab-avail')))
button.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Literature')]").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#literature_div h4')))
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#literature_div h4")

litrature = []

for item in rows:
    item = item.text
    litrature.append(item)
    print("Data from COLUMN 1:")
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Someone with more knowledge of python waits can certainly improve on my wait lines.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#!/"
d = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[type=text]').send_keys('AKT1 (3 mutations)')
d.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-default.btn-tab-avail")))
btn.click()
d.find_element_by_css_selector("[heading=Literature]").click()

ele = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#literature_div [ng-repeat]"), "PMID"))
eles = d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#literature_div [ng-repeat]")

for item in eles:
    print(item.text,"\n")

d.quit()
```

Comment: When I try to click on the 'Next ' button under the 'literature' table, I get the following error: "Message: The element reference of <div class="ng-scope"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
"
Following is the line I added to click on the "NEXT" buton:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)"]').click()

Comment: Hiya - This sounds like a new question. And are you running my script or the other answer?

Comment: You can ping me here with @qharr when posted if you want